# AFNetworking 2.0 AFHTTPRequestOperation PUT bad request (400)" on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, afnetworking-2

Looking to perform the Parse Cloud REST function PUT to increment a value

```
 curl -X PUT \
   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: RFtvvfffdfgwbeERRGFGFFGFHNIc6ubgwpJ5LL" \
   -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: SsYTGDFGDSFSDHGGGFTY56TXC435GGFhrfs0O4u0K" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d '{"qtyAllocated":{"__op":"Increment","amount":1}}' \
   https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Lot/WrXPiXtB89
```

I came with this sample code from Chris Wagner article of How To Synchronize Core Data with a Web Service, All other methods works but not PUT, this one returns with this error

```
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8dbc210> { URL: https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Lot/WrXPiXtB89 } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Access-Control-Request-Method" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 89;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 06 Aug 2014 03:24:57 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.0";
    "Set-Cookie" = "_parse_session=BAh7BkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlZjAzNDQxZDgwZDI5MDBhMjJhYzVjYTFjMGY2MzhiNTk%3D--bd6b3ec8f339e5928d44f29875b8f0d22e8f88fc; domain=.parse.com; path=/; expires=Fri, 05-Sep-2014 03:24:57 GMT; secure; HttpOnly";
    Status = "400 Bad Request";
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.047238";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}
```

in my subclass on AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

```
+ (instancetype)sharedSDAFParseAPIClient {
    static SDAFParseAPIClient *sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedClient = [[SDAFParseAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kSDFParseAPIBaseURLString]];
    });

    return sharedClient;
}

-(instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self) {
        AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer alloc] init];
        [requestSerializer setValue:kSDFParseAPIApplicationId forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
        [requestSerializer setValue:kSDFParseAPIKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
        [self setRequestSerializer:requestSerializer];
        [self setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
    }

    return self;
}

- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)UPDATERequestForClass:(NSString *)className
                                  forObjectWithId:(NSString *)objectId
                                           parameters:(NSDictionary *)field
                                          success:(SuccessBlockType)success
                                          failure:(FailureBlockType)failure {

   __block NSDictionary *parameters = nil;

    [field enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL* stop) {

        NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"__op\":\"Increment\",\"amount\":%@}",value];

       parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:jsonString forKey:key];

    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self PUT:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"classes/%@/%@", className, objectId] parameters:parameters success:success failure:failure];
    return operation;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You really shouldn't put your actual keys in the post.

Comment: Timothy - thanks for the input, the keys are fake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I figure out that the scape sequence on the *jsonString bellow where passing through the NSJSONSerialization. I do not know how works on the others methods of the Chris Wagner article "How To Synchronize Core Data with a Web Service", but do not work on PUT, as least for me.

```
        NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ {\"__op\":\"Increment\",\"amount\":%@}",value];
```

Since I use as source an array of parameters, finally I translate the *jsonString to this:

```
__block NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[field enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL* stop) {

   [parameters addEntriesFromDictionary:@{key: @{@"__op":@"Increment", @"amount":value}}];

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use use the native iOS SDK instead, it does the same REST calls under the covers.

You'll save yourself a lot of pain and effort using the SDK.

UPDATE:

To the downvoters, it is an entirely valid answer to say "don't reinvent the wheel". Parse provide a rich API/SDK that has fully tested code to prevent people from having these problems.

I can understand wanting to do it yourself for learning reasons, but unless there's some really good reason not to just use the SDK in this case, my answer stands.

Comment: Here goes a good reason:  How about decoupling your Networking Code from Parse and their SDK, so that you can easily move to another Service provider or your own API.